Spotify OAuth 2.0 Authentication
How do I handle OAuth 2.0 authentication with Spotify API in a Node.js application? I'm trying to authenticate users via Spotify in my Node.js application using OAuth 2.0. I want to know how to implement the full authorization code flow, handle access token requests, and refresh tokens. What are the common pitfalls, such as redirect URI mismatches, token expiration, and scope issues, and how can I address them in my implementation?
What did I try?
I set up OAuth 2.0 with Spotify in a Node.js app, redirecting users to the authorization page and receiving the code.
What did I expect?
To exchange the authorization code for an access token and handle token expiration automatically.
What actually resulted?
I encountered issues with token exchange, redirect URI mismatches, and trouble refreshing expired tokens.

Try to find search first, The authorization code flow in Spotify by node.js handled many times.
